# Scala : In properties file multiple key's having same value is there any possibility i can do this in single line of code

Tags: scala

I have a properties file Test.properties file with the key value as

```
claim.type.dent=Dental
claim.type.fclty=Dental
```

here dent and fclty key having the same value like this I have many key's having the same value.

```
def standalizeClaimType(claim : String): String={ 
  var claimTypeDescription = standalizationProp.getString(Standardiz‌​ationConstants.CLAIM‌​_TYPE + SplCharsConsta‌​nts.DOT+claim.toLowe‌​rCase()) 
  return claimTypeDescription 
} 
object StandardizationConstants {
  val GENDER_TYPE="gender.type"
  val CLAIM_TYPE="claim.type"
}
```

I have written the above code which will get the exact value what I am expecting however for this I have to write 2 lines of code, if I have 10 keys with the same value I have to write 10 lines of code. so is there any facility available in Scala I can write the 10 line of code in one line, like if any of the key matches it should give the value.

Please help me with this.

Comment: where are the codes "`I have written the above code which will get the exact value`"?

Comment: claim.type.dent=Dental

claim.type.fclty=Dental

Comment: those are not codes . They are your properties file's data. Please post whatever you've tried pointing out the issue.

Comment: Hi Please find the below code what I am  trying,

def standalizeClaimType(claim : String): String={

    var claimTypeDescription=standalizationProp.getString(StandardizationConstants.CLAIM_TYPE+SplCharsConstants.DOT+claim.toLowerCase())

    return claimTypeDescription

  }

 

 

object StandardizationConstants {

 

  val GENDER_TYPE="gender.type"

  val CLAIM_TYPE="claim.type"

 

}

Comment: Probably not very helpful but this is one of the reasons for our migration to Typesafe/Lightbend Config: https://github.com/lightbend/config

Comment: how you generated `standalizationProp` and `SplCharsConsta‌​nts`?